# How to identify cause of system lock on debian squeeze?

Tags: debian, freeze, powersave

I have a desktop system at work with debian squeeze installed.  Every couple days or so, when I come in in the morning, the system appears to be asleep and won't wake up.  I suspect it goes into power save mode and then doesn't receive the wake up signal when I click the mouse or touch the keyboard.

Does anyone know where I should look in order to start tracking this down?  Like log files, etc?

I doubt it, but maybe the fact that I'm using a mac aluminum usb keyboard and a wireless usb mouse (that has an off switch) has something to do with it?  Maybe, when I turn my mouse off at the end of the day, the system loses track of the device somehow?  I dunno :P.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something I ran into before in my 11.10->12.04 upgrade.

Use

```
$ lsusb
```

To find your mouse/keyboard product and vendor ids.
If the output for your device is:

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52e Logitech, Inc.
```

**`046d`** is you vendor id and **`c52e`** is your product ID

Then edit your rules:

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/90-keyboardwakeup.rules
```

and add the correct product and vendor id's with:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="YOUR VENDOR ID HERE", ATTRS{idProduct}=="YOUR PRODUCT ID HERE" RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo enabled > /sys$env{DEVPATH}/../power/wakeup'"
```

Then reboot your machine. Hopefully that fixes things. Holler if it doesn't.